# How to add sectional variable header in gtsummary tbl_summary

Tags: r, dplyr, header, gtsummary, gt

I have a current table creating using the following code:

```
table1 <- 
  ptbl %>%
  dplyr::select( pt_gender.factor, pt_race.factor, pt_ethnicity.factor, education.factor, employed.factor,marital.factor,
                 home_smoker.factor,quit_support.factor,past7.factor) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    label = list(pt_gender.factor ~ "Gender",
                 pt_race.factor ~ "Race",
                 pt_ethnicity.factor ~ "Ethnicity",
                 education.factor ~ "Education",
                 employed.factor ~ "Employed",
                 marital.factor ~ "Marital Status",
                 home_smoker.factor ~ "Live with smoker",
                 quit_support.factor ~ "People around are very supportive of quitting smoking",
                 past7.factor ~ "In the past 7 days, did you smoke a cigarette (even a puff)?"))
```

I am trying to add two sectional titles to my table, one is "Demographics", and the other one is "Smoking Habit".

I want my table like

**Demographics**
Gender
....
Race
...
Ethnicity
...
...

**Smoking Habit**
Live with smoker
...
People around are very supportive of quitting smoking
.....
[image]

Is there a function to do it?

Comment: Do you want the "sectional titles" on the same line as the column labels? If not, then you could use spanner column labels which sit above the column labels.

Comment: @Tob I want the sectional titles between column labels! So it will look like a bold column label without any data on the right